# TFS build vNext allows to change variables not settables at queue time

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

I´m configuring a TFS2017 (Update 3) vNext build which have some internal vars with values that shouldn´t be modified on queue time (the vars were created with a default value and the "settable at queue time" flag unchecked).

Problem comes due to the fact that a "add new variable" button is available on queue time (even for users who don´t have permissions to modify the build definition). If some of this users queues a new build and adds a new variable whose name matches with the name of the var already defined, the value of this var is overwrited! (even when is not settable at queue time). This gives to every user with queue build permissions the ability of "hack" the build (which means important security issues since the build agent will use this values for privileged actions)

Any way of hidding this button or any approach to workaround the problem?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, there is no way/settings to hiden the add variables button at queue time.

And I posted an user voice [Add permission to add variables at build queue time for TFS and VSTS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/35027002-add-permission-to-add-variables-at-build-queue-tim) which suggest this feature. You can vote and follow up.

Besides, you can use any of the below workarounds to avoid the variable be overwritten (such as to avoid the variable `var` with value `myvar` to be overwritten) **at queue time**:

[image]

#### Workaround 1: use PowerShell to reset the variable

Add a PowerShell script at the beginning of the build definition and set the variable var's value in PowerShell script:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=var]myvar"
```

[image]

So even someone add the same variable `var` at queue time, the value won’t be overwritten during build. The variable var's value always is `myvar`.

[image]

#### Workaround 2: set the variable var as settable at queue time

Since the user who has no permission to edit the variable definition, if you set `var` as **Settable at queue time**, the user can only view the variable var and can not change the value.

[image]

Even if the user add variable, he/she can not add the variable with name `var` any more.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Marina.

Regarding the workaround 2: I´ve made some test and seems that users who do not have edit permissions on the Build definition are able to modify the vars which are settables at queue time... I´m using TFS2017 Update 3.

Regards.

Comment: @Josto If the answer helps you solve the problem, could you please mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer? And it will also benefit others who meet similar questions :)

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, it seems that the workaround which best fits our current needs is #1 (powershell script). Thanks Marina :)

Anyhow, there is no way of achieve the #2 in our environment since users who do NOT have edit permissions on the build definition are able to modify settable at queue time vars. Has TFS2017 any special behaviour on this or I am missing anything?

Regards

Comment: You should ask the user who has permission to edit the build definition to change the variable `var` (as above example) as settable at queue time, so that when users (who have not edit permission) queuing the build, they can neither adding the same variable name `var` nor  changing the value of `var` at queue time.